# Set "middle page" to rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have website with adult content. If user visit site first time, we need to show him message "If you're 18 years old you can enter." and "Enter" button. How can I show this page once and if user click on enter, show him homepage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ideal situation to store something in the user's session, and redirect them based on whether or not that something is set. Have a `before_filter` in your `application_controller.rb` that looks like this:

```
before_filter :check_age

private

def check_age
  return true if session[:age_check]
  redirect_to age_verification_path
end
```

In your age verification controller, set `session[:age_check]` to true if the user clicks on a link. Then the `before_filter` will let them access the site as you'd expect.